# SQL Server XML field swap values of two nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a rather big table with an XML field at the end. This field contains some properties in many tdf tags. All  tag has a Field and a Unit attribute and a wsd node:

```
<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FileDate" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="17.11.2015 19:25:29" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FormIdent" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="XXXXXX-AAAA" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName2.ItemData_CycleTime" Unit="s">
  <wsd Value="70" />
</tdf>
```

What I want to do is to swap the value (tdf/wsd Value) of each DataFieldName1.FormIdent and DataFieldName2.ItemData_CycleTime fields in all records. So the example above should be changed like this:

```
<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FileDate" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="17.11.2015 19:25:29" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FormIdent" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="70" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName2.ItemData_CycleTime" Unit="s">
  <wsd Value="XXXXXX-AAAA" />
</tdf>
```

Can I do this without declaring a cursor on the records of the table that contains the XML field? What is the preferred and most secure method doing this in an XML type field? There are many XML fields that doesn't even contain the records I would like to swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following XQuery. It is following a happy path.

*"...There are many XML fields that doesn't even contain the records I would like to swap..."*. You never provided DDL and sample data population. You can always add a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` statement to filter out not needed rows.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FileDate" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="17.11.2015 19:25:29" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FormIdent" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="XXXXXX-AAAA" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName2.ItemData_CycleTime" Unit="s">
  <wsd Value="70" />
</tdf>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE @tbl
SET xmldata = xmldata.query('
let $w1 := tdf[@Field="DataFieldName1.FormIdent"]/wsd/@Value
let $w2 := tdf[@Field="DataFieldName2.ItemData_CycleTime"]/wsd/@Value
for $x in tdf
return if ($x/@Field = "DataFieldName1.FormIdent") then 
        element tdf {
            $x/@*, <wsd Value="{$w2}" />
    }
    else if ($x/@Field = "DataFieldName2.ItemData_CycleTime") then 
        element tdf {
            $x/@*, <wsd Value="{$w1}" />
    }
    else $x
');

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FileDate" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="17.11.2015 19:25:29" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName1.FormIdent" Unit="">
  <wsd Value="70" />
</tdf>
<tdf Field="DataFieldName2.ItemData_CycleTime" Unit="s">
  <wsd Value="XXXXXX-AAAA" />
</tdf>
```